# About view in MVC framework

Tags: php, templates

In a view, can I declare a form object and make forms using it to create forms? Should it be a variable that you will send to the view?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        hello world

        <?php foreach($posts as $post):?>
            <h2><?php echo $post['title'];?></h2>
        <?php endforeach;?>

        <?php
            $form = new Form
            $form->start('files');
            $form->input('text','name','50');
            $form->end();
        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of HTML code?

Comment: What mvc framework are you using?

Comment: my framework i not have presenter, i have registry and loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it matters which MVC framework you are using. Your page controller should initialize the form object which is then passed to your view. Your view should only contain html and API calls via the form object (variable accessible by view).

Comment: variables are stored in an array and passed to the view from the extract operation, as they should be. Do you view files right solution is to use a class to create ormularzy or how to solve this?

Comment: After working extensively with the Symfony Framework, I can tell you  the actions initialize the form objects (along with other template variables) which are then passed to the view via a decorator pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the main concepts behind mvc are separation and reuse - I'd say create another form and pass that as a variable to the main view.  that way, you can reuse the form in other places if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can include files for your view classes. you can pass parameters to those included files with get paramters by setting

```
$_GET["key1"]="somekey";
```

and using

```
$_get["key1"]
```

in the included file to get varable.